# Planning a trip to Niagara Falls on US side only (Amtrak)

Tags: usa, planning, amtrak, niagara-falls

We will be taking the train to visit Niagara. Following is the plan which we have created. We will be taking the Empire Service from New York Penn to reach Niagara Falls. If, the train reaches on time, then we will have some time to visit Niagara fall at night to view it.

This is the first time, we will be going there so would appreciate if someone can shed some light on this:

1. Is the time gap between the train enough knowing that Empire Service has 52% probability to travel on time (based on Amtrak Website)
2. During the return trip, we will be arriving at 23:45 in New York Penn. Will restaurants be opened in the station at that late at night? If there any waiting room where we can wait for our next train at 3:00 AM in the morning.

Below is the itinerary which I am planning.

[image: Amtrak Tip Plan]

Comment: Can you split the questions?  As it stands it's way too broad.

Comment: @Karlson I mentioned the questions into 5 parts. Do you want me to reduce the number of questions?

Comment: Split them by subject, Amtrak, Currency, Siteseeing.

Comment: Also, currency, any bank will gladly exchange your hard currency into our monopoly money ;)

Comment: You've asked several questions. Generally posts containing multiple different questions get closed as too broad - you may need to split them off to other ones.

Comment: @soumya In separate questions!!!

Comment: @MarkMayo I will minimize the question only to Amtrak based.

Comment: @Karlson I will minimize the question to only Amtrak based.

Comment: @Soumya Can you also rephrase your last question?  I am not sure what kind of information you're looking for.

Comment: @Karlson Sure. Will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well let's try to answer these in order:

1. You should be more concerned about Northeast Regional arriving early enough than about the Empire Service leaving on time if you're concerned about the time between trains.  Around that time in the morning the trains run pretty well so unless there is a problem with the equipment, which have happened before you should have plenty of time to make your connection.
2. There are several places around the Penn Station that report to be open 24 hours but some of them are actually located outside the station itself.  I can't vouch for the quality  of what you will get at that hour but it's food.  There is a sitting "lounge" if you will for Amtrak but it's small from the pictures and [Yelp](http://www.yelp.com/biz/new-york-penn-station-new-york) and not particularly comfortable.  Personally I find it generally dismal, crowded, stuffy, and uncomfortable but then again I mostly use it during rush hour.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Thats why I have kept 3.5 hours between the two trains. Also thanks for suggesting Yelp application.

Comment: Is there an operating hours to visit the Niagara fall at night?

Comment: Different question.